# Extending a JavaScript object function

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wordpress

I need to extend a `tinymce.plugins.WordPress` function from my `tinymce.plugins.XYZ` object. I need to extend `_hideButtons` within this core object:

```
(function() {
    var DOM = tinymce.DOM;

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.WordPress', {
        mceTout : 0,

        _hideButtons : function() {
            if ( !this.mceTout )    
                return;

            if ( document.getElementById('wp_editbtns') )
                tinymce.DOM.hide('wp_editbtns');

            if ( document.getElementById('wp_gallerybtns') )
                tinymce.DOM.hide('wp_gallerybtns');

            clearTimeout(this.mceTout);

            this.mceTout = 0;
        };

    }); 

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('wordpress', tinymce.plugins.WordPress);

})();
```

here is the object that needs to do the extending:

```
(function() {  

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.XYZ', {  
         /* here */
    });  

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('youtube', tinymce.plugins.XYZ);  

})();
```

Thank you for the help!

**For reference:** I am adding `edit` and `delete` buttons to a custom shortcode element (like wp gallery)

Comment: i guess, your post is no real question (my +1 equals this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to extend it. You just need to over write the function in question.

Comment: Could you clarify with an example?  That would be very helpful to me.